Samba is baffling - weird guest account stuff
I have used Samba occasionally over 25 years and it never ceases to baffle me.
Bob has a basic guest share created in his home directory.  Other devices on the local network can access the share and create files and directories, including subdirectories and files in the subdirectories.  On the host itself, root can access the share with smbclient and do the same.
However, on the host, if bob accesses the share with smbclient, bob can only create files and directories in the root of the share.  Bob can't create subdirectories or create files anywhere other than the root directory.  Why is bob treated differently to root and other devices?  Why is bob's guest connection to samba with smbclient treated differently to other clients' guest connection?  Weirdly, bob CAN create subdirectories and files in subdirectories using KDE Dolphin (a gui file manager).
Now, (weirder still) if I remove bob from the samba password file, he CAN create subdirectories and files in directories with smbclient.   Why does removing bob from the samba password file give him MORE rights?
Now, anything created in the share is owned by 'nobody' per default behaviour.  I want everything owned by bob, so I add 'guest account = bob' to smb.conf and now NO-ONE can create subdirectories or files in directories other than the root of the share!  Bob owns the share directory and the newly-created subdirectories (they're now created in his name).  If the Samba guest user is connecting as bob, why on earth can't it create subdirectories/files???  (This behaviour is the same regardless of whether bob is in the samba password file.)
All of this is documented below.  I would be most grateful if anyone could explain this.
bob@host:~$ ls -la
total 279356
drwx-----x 111 bob  bob       4096 Jul 20 17:29  .
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root      4096 May 29 17:14  ..
...
drwxr-xrwx   2 bob  bob       4096 Jul 20 17:29  fckngsmb
...
bob@host:~$ cat /var/lib/samba/usershares/fckngsmb  
#VERSION 2
path=/home/bob/fckngsmb
comment=
usershare_acl=S-1-1-0:f
guest_ok=y
sharename=fckngsmb
bob@host:~/fckngsmb$ testparm
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed by GnuTLS (e.g. NTLM as a compatibility fallback)

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
       log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
       logging = file
       map to guest = Bad User
       max log size = 1000
       obey pam restrictions = Yes
       pam password change = Yes
       panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
       passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
       passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
       server role = standalone server
       unix password sync = Yes
       usershare allow guests = Yes
       idmap config * : backend = tdb

bob@host:~/fkngsmb$ cd ..
bob@host:~$ smbclient -N //host/fckngsmb
Anonymous login successful
Try "help" to get a list of possible commands.
smb: \> mkdir made-by-bob
smb: \> cd made-by-bob\
smb: \made-by-bob\> mkdir subdir
NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED making remote directory \made-by-bob\subdir
smb: \made-by-bob\> put /etc/hosts hosts
NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED opening remote file \made-by-bob\hosts
smb: \made-by-bob\> exit
bob@host:~$ su -
Password:  
root@host:~# smbclient -N //host/fckngsmb
Try "help" to get a list of possible commands.
smb: \> mkdir made-by-root
smb: \> cd made-by-root\
smb: \made-by-root\> mkdir subdir
smb: \made-by-root\> put /etc/hosts hosts
putting file /etc/hosts as \made-by-root\hosts (99.1 kb/s) (average 99.1 kb/s)
smb: \made-by-root\> exit
root@host:~#  
logout
bob@host:~$ cd fckngsmb/
bob@host:~/fckngsmb$ ls -la *
made-by-bob:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup 4096 Jul 20 18:24 .
drwxr-xrwx 4 bob    bob     4096 Jul 20 18:25 ..

made-by-root:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 3 nobody nogroup 4096 Jul 20 18:25 .
drwxr-xrwx 4 bob    bob     4096 Jul 20 18:25 ..
-rwxr--r-- 1 nobody nogroup  203 Jul 20 18:25 hosts
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup 4096 Jul 20 18:25 subdir

bob@host:~/fckngsmb$ su -
Password:  
root@host:~# smbpasswd -x bob
Deleted user bob.
root@host:~#  
logout
bob@host:~/fckngsmb$ smbclient -N //host/fckngsmb
Try "help" to get a list of possible commands.
smb: \> mkdir made-by-bob-again
smb: \> cd made-by-bob-again\
smb: \made-by-bob-again\> mkdir subdirectory
smb: \made-by-bob-again\> put /etc/hosts hosts
putting file /etc/hosts as \made-by-bob-again\hosts (99.1 kb/s) (average 99.1 kb/s)
smb: \made-by-bob-again\> exit
bob@host:~/fckngsmb$ su -
Password:  
root@host:~# nano /etc/samba/smb.conf (<-- added guest account = bob) 
root@host:~# systemctl restart smbd nmbd
root@host:~# testparm
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed by GnuTLS (e.g. NTLM as a compatibility fallback)

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
       guest account = bob
       log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
       logging = file
       map to guest = Bad User
       max log size = 1000
       obey pam restrictions = Yes
       pam password change = Yes
       panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
       passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
       passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
       server role = standalone server
       unix password sync = Yes
       usershare allow guests = Yes
       idmap config * : backend = tdb

root@host:~# rm -rf /home/bob/fckngsmb/*
root@host:~# smbclient -N //host/fckngsmb
Try "help" to get a list of possible commands.
smb: \> mkdir made-by-root
smb: \> cd made-by-root\
smb: \made-by-root\> mkdir subdirectory
NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED making remote directory \made-by-root\subdirectory
smb: \made-by-root\> put /etc/hosts hosts
NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED opening remote file \made-by-root\hosts
smb: \made-by-root\> exit
root@host:~#  
logout

bob@host:~/fckngsmb$ smbclient -N //host/fckngsmb
Anonymous login successful
Try "help" to get a list of possible commands.
smb: \> mkdir made-by-bob
smb: \> cd made-by-bob\
smb: \made-by-bob\> mkdir subdirectory
NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED making remote directory \made-by-bob\subdirectory
smb: \made-by-bob\> put /etc/hosts hosts
NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED opening remote file \made-by-bob\hosts
smb: \made-by-bob\> exit

